# No more custom libraries on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-libraries

On Windows 10, in the left pane in File Explorer, under the "This PC" node, we have some 'special' folders like "Desktop", "Documents", "Videos", "Music", etc.

All very nice, but unlike in Windows 7, I can't find a way to add my own 'Library' folders, like e.g. "Books".

Is this gone in Windows 10, or just well undocumented and hidden?

Is there maybe a third party utility or even registry hack that I can use to make these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### I can't find a way to add my own `Library` folders, like "Books"

See below for three different ways to add a Library.

- Create New Library using New Context Menu
- Create New Library using File Explorer Ribbon
- Create New Library using "Include in Library" Context Menu

Note:

- You may have to [Show libraries](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4222-libraries-navigation-pane-hide-show-windows-10-a.html) first if your Library folders have  been hidden.

---

#### Create New Library using New Context Menu

> 1. Open Libraries in File Explorer.
> 2. Right click or press and hold on an empty area in the Libraries window, click/tap on New, and click/tap on Library. (see screenshot
>      below)
>
>    [image]
> 3. Type a name you want for the new library. (see screenshot below)
>
>    [image]
> 4. You will now be able to include folders to the new library. (see screenshot below)
>
>    [image]

---

#### Create New Library using File Explorer Ribbon

> 1. Open Libraries in File Explorer.
> 2. Click/tap on the Home tab, click/tap on New item in the ribbon, and click/tap on Library. (see screenshot below)
>
>    [image]
> 3. Type a name you want for the new library. (see screenshot below)
>
>    [image]
> 4. You will now be able to include folders to the new library. (see screenshot below)
>
>    [image]

---

#### Create New Library using "Include in Library" Context Menu

> 1. Open File Explorer, and browse to the folder you want to include in a new library.
> 2. Right click or press and hold on the folder, click/tap on Include in library, and click/tap on Create a new library. (see screenshot
>      below)
>
>    [image]
> 3. A new library will be created with the folder included, and the new library will be named the same as the included folder.
>
>    Notes:
>
>    - If you like, you can rename the new library anything you like.
>    - You will also be able to include more folders to the new library.
>
>    [image]

Source [How to Create a New Library in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8867-library-create-new-library-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Oooh, thank you. I wondered where the hell you got a Libraries folder from, then found that mine was configured to not display, otherwise I would have figured something out with it. Thanks for the detail in your answer.

Comment: @ProfK Thanks for the feedback. I've added a short note about unhiding libraries if necessary.